# Spring Security Java Config Multiple Group Search Base

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring Security 3.2.5 with Java config and LDAP authentication/authorization.

We have a requirement to search for groups in two separate trees in LDAP.

ou=groups

and

ou=Groups,ou=webapps,ou=Applications

I have searched and have been unable to find any information on this topic.

This is my current code which is working fine:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper, LdapContextSource contextSource, AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {


    builder
    .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper)
        .contextSource(contextSource)
        .userSearchFilter("cn={0}")
        .userSearchBase("ou=Users")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups");


}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    builder
    .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper)
        .contextSource(contextSource)
        .userSearchFilter("cn={0}")
        .userSearchBase("ou=Users")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=Groups,ou=webapps,ou=Applications");
```

Which understandably does not work.

Anyone have any pointers on where to start?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I'm looking for the exact same thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to create an implementation of `org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` which can call multiple instances of `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`. Then create one `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`for each 'groupSearchBase' that I wanted to query.

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper, LdapContextSource contextSource, AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {

    MultipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator multipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator = new MultipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(
        new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, "ou=Groups,ou=webapps,ou=Applications"),
        new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, "ou=groups"));

    builder
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(multipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator)
            .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper) 
            .contextSource(contextSource)
            .userSearchFilter("cn={0}")
            .userSearchBase("ou=Users");
}

class MultipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {
    private List<LdapAuthoritiesPopulator> authoritiesPopulators;

    public MultipleLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(LdapAuthoritiesPopulator...authoritiesPopulators) {
        this.authoritiesPopulators = asList(authoritiesPopulators);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = authoritiesPopulators.stream()
            .map(authPopulator -> authPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(userData, username))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```