# How to handle exceptions from Spring Boot's LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I have the following web security in a Spring Boot application:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(contextSource)
                .userSearchBase("OU=users,DC=example,DC=com")
                .userSearchFilter("userName={0}")
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(authoritiesPopulator)
                .and()
            // fall back to the admin group if not found
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(contextSource)
                .userSearchBase("OU=admins,DC=example,DC=com")
                .userSearchFilter("userName={0}")
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(authoritiesPopulator)
            ;
    }
```

The idea is pretty straightforward: try searching in the `users` group and if the user is not found, then try the `admin` group.  All of this works great until something goes wrong with the first lookup.  If the `users` group suddenly goes away, for example, the first lookup will generate an exception and the second lookup is never attempted.
Is there a way to configure `LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer` or perhaps `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to not abort the whole process when one of the authentication provider exceptions out?

Answer (score 0):

following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490510/1211547) - maybe this (untested code)

```
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(contextSource)
                .userSearchBase("DC=example,DC=com")
                //.userSearchFilter("&((userName={0}))")
                .userDnPatterns("userName={0},OU=users", "userName={0},OU=admins")
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(authoritiesPopulator))
    }
```

Comment: This could be a workaround in some cases, but I think only in the case where you can use the `userDnPatterns` to produce a fully qualified DN, which is not the case in my situation.  I actually have to perform a full-on LDAP search to locate the user.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42441496/1211547) also sounds similar, maybe could be adopted for userSearchBase